# Time complexity for this algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, analysis-of-algorithms

If I don't have a condition in the second loop the time complexity will be $O(n^2)$ from:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{m}c$$

So what happens in this case:

```
int n = 5;
int m = 10;
int rnd; //rnd is a random number between 0 and m
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
    {
       if(j==rnd) 
          break;
    }
}
```

Is it $O(n)$ or still $O(n^2)$. Or I have to proof it in best, average and worst case?

Comment: Why $\Theta(n^2) $? It is $\Theta(nm)$. Regarding your question in the worst case, it is still $\Theta(nm)$. In the best case, it is $\Theta(1)$ and in average case I guess it is again $\Theta(nm)$

Comment: @Ahmad, in the best case, it is still $\Theta(n)$; the `break;` breaks only out of the outer loop, so the loop is entered $n$ times which still takes $\Omega(n)$ time.

Comment: @Ahmad: since $n$ and $m$ only differ by a constant factor, and the complexity considerations target at large $n$ and $m$, it is OK to write $O(n^2)$.

Comment: @Ronald, nothing in the question suggests that $n$ and $m$ only differ by a constant factor in the generalized situation.

Comment: @MeesdeVries OK I got your point and understand you're right. We simply know too little about $n$ and $m$, even if the program code assigns values to them.

Comment: A small note to my edit: I couldn't just repair the inner loop (I changed $i$ to $j$ in the condition, which eliminated an endless loop) because too few characters were changed. This is why I changed the $\Theta$ into a big $O$. I don't think it makes a big difference for the question, but feel free to re-edit.

Comment: @Ronald So the correct way of this is worst is $O(nm)$, best is $\Omega(n)$ and average is $\frac{nm}{n} = \Theta(m)$?

Comment: As an aside, an actual program built from this source may well run in $\Theta(1)$ time; basically, the compiler may be able to determine the "closed form" result of the loop.

Comment: @Ronald I don't get the usefulness of two parameters here. He could use *n* for both loops.

Comment: @Ahmed yes a single $n$ would do it for this question; it wouldn't change the principal complexity consideration. I just see it as doing something with an $n \times m$ matrix or table, without specifying the exact action. Obviously that unspecified action can potentially have a significant influence on the complexity of the algorithm.

Comment: The worst is definitely $O(nm)$, as your rnd could be $m$. If rnd equals zero, you'd have $n$ iterations, hence a lower bound of $\Omega(n)$. On average rnd will be $\frac{1}{2}m$ which will cause $\frac{1}{2}nm$ iterations. This is still a complexity of $O(nm)$ though. The $\Theta$ notation has strong implications as it defines both an upper and a lower bound.

Comment: @Ronald How can I express the average case in a mathematical definition in order to calculate it and to proof it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I give the definitions of the operators, the way I use them.

$f(n) = O(g(n))$ means
$$\exists_{k>0} \exists_{n_0} \forall_{n > n_0} \ f(n) \leq k g(n)$$

$f(n) = \Omega(g(n))$ means
$$\exists_{k>0} \exists_{n_0} \forall_{n > n_0} \ f(n) \geq k g(n)$$

$f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$ means
$$\exists_{k_0 > 0} \exists_{k_1 > 0} \exists_{n_0} \forall_{n > n_0} \ k_0 g(n) \leq f(n) \leq k_1 g(n)$$

I'll call the integer random value $r$, and $0 \leq r \leq m$.

Furthermore I assume that the distribution of $r$ is uniform. Hence every value between $0$ and $m$ is equally likely.

The best that can happen is that $r = 0$. This eliminates the inner loop. The remaining number of iterations is $n$.
The complexity of the algorithm in this special case is obviously $O(n)$.
Every iteration consists of a fixed number of low level operations. Hence the upper bound is given by $O(n)$. The lower bound is given by $\Omega(n)$.
Therefor in the best case of $r = 0$, the complexity of the algorithm is $\Theta(n)$.

The worst that can happen is that $r = m$. The number of iterations will be $nm$. This yields an upper bound of $O(nm)$, and by the same reasoning as above, a lower bound of $\Omega(nm)$. The worst case complexity of the algorithm is $\Theta(nm)$.

On average, $r = \frac{1}{2}m$, due to the uniform distribution. The number of iterations will be $\frac{1}{2}nm$. Because the multiplier $\frac{1}{2}$ vanishes in the big $O$ notation, the complexity will still be $O(nm)$.

This means, that the algorithm as a whole has a complexity of $O(nm)$, with a lower bound of $\Omega(n)$.
Because of the different functions ($n \neq nm$), the complexity of the algorithm cannot be expressed in the $\Theta$ notation.